# Should we expose every object as spring bean?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

```
class TibcoPasswordRetriever {

    private TibcoPasswordUtil tibcoPasswordUtil;

    public TibcoPasswordRetriever(TibcoPasswordUtil tibcoPasswordUtil) {
        this.tibcoPasswordUtil = tibcoPasswordUtil;
    }

}

class TibcoPasswordRetriever {

    private TibcoPasswordUtil tibcoPasswordUtil;

    public TibcoPasswordRetriever() {
        this.tibcoPasswordUtil = new TibcoPasswordUtil();
    }

}
```

These are two definitions of TibcoPasswordRetriever.

Question : I am using TibcoPasswordUtil in TibcoPasswordRetriever class only. Is dependency injection still a good idea?

Further question: Should we create expose every possible object as spring bean (just because it is possible to do that)

Comment: Note that **DI** stands for **Dependency Inversion**, not **Dependency Injection**. Totally different concepts of which you should care about the first.

Comment: what does that util class has? are you calling any methods in util class? is it wokring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question : I am using TibcoPasswordUtil in TibcoPasswordRetriever
>   class only. Is dependency injection still a good idea?

Probably dependency injection is good idea if `TibcoPasswordUtil` is a `Singletone`. You did not provide `TibcoPasswordUtil` class in the question. Addind `Util` to name does not mean many here. Consider writing more about architecture and context.

> Further question: Should we create expose every possible object as
>   spring bean (just because it is possible to do that)

No it is not, cause better solution would be not to be dependent so much on framework.
Ask yourself questions like:

If you don't have to, then why is the advantage of it?

Why is the benefit of not doing so?

Like i wrote above less coupled code is better. In the future it would be easier to for example change framework.

Answer (score 1):

No you should not expose every object as a Spring bean unless there is a need. Those classes which you feel necessarily has to be instantiated and maintained by the framework has to be made a bean. An example of such a class would be a database access class. Those kind of classes could have multiple implementations and choosing which implementation to use could depend on some external configuration. In such cases you can delegate the responsibility of managing the instances to the framework.

If you are sure there is only one type of Util class you are using and there are no added complexities in managing its instances (like it has to be a Singleton), you don't have to make it a bean.